# Mockito mock CassandraOperation Slice method

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, mockito, cassandra-3.0

I am using the Mockito framework to write the mock Junit test cases below is my Service class to test the Junit test code

```
public class UserService {
@Autowired
private CassandraOperations template

public UserDTO getUserDTO(String date, String pagingState) {
        Select select = QueryBuilder.select().all()
                .from("tbl_user");
        select.where(QueryBuilder.eq(date, date));
        select.setFetchSize(30);
        if (pagingState != null) {
            select.setPagingState(PagingState.fromString(pagingState));
        }
        Slice<UserDTO> usgerDTO = template.slice(select, UserDTO.class);
        if(usgerDTO.hasNext()) {
        }
        return usgerDTO.get();
}
```

Test case Class is writted

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)    
public class UserServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
    private UserService service ;

    @Mock
    private CassandraOperations template;

    @Mock
    private UserDTO userDTO;
    private String date= "2019-09";
 @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void test() {
        Slice<UserDTO>  userDTO= Mockito.mock(Slice.class);
        Select select = Mockito.mock(Select.class);

                Mockito.when(template.slice(select, UserDTO.class)).thenReturn(userDTO);
        metricReportDTO = service.getUserDTO(date, null);


    }
    }
```

I am getting Null values on this line

```
Slice<UserDTO> usgerDTO = template.slice(select, UserDTO.class);
```

Can you please helm me how to test template.slice method

Note: I should not use the PowerMockito

Comment: Could you please try to use `any()` instead of mocked `select`? If it doesn't help please add the stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet doesn't make sense in that you call `service.getMetricsReports(date, null)` in your test but your `UserService` code example only has the method `getUserDTO`. Assuming that is just a typo then you need to use matchers to get the mock to work in your `when`.

```java
Mockito.when(template.slice(any(Select.class), eq(UserDTO.class))).thenReturn(userDTO);
```

This means whenever the first param is a class of type `Select` and the second is equal to `UserDTO.class` then return the `userDTO` if those 2 params don't match those conditions it will return `null`.

You can also make it match the exact `Select` assuming it has an overridden `equals` method. In the case where you send a `null` `pagingState` then something like:

```java
Select stubSelect = QueryBuilder.select().all()
                .from("tbl_user");
        stubSelect.where(QueryBuilder.eq(date, date));
        stubSelect.setFetchSize(30);

Mockito.when(template.slice(eq(stubSelect), eq(UserDTO.class))).thenReturn(userDTO);
```

Comment: Yeah its typo mistake edited the question thanks for your answer